# How to extract key value pairs from a specific format string using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with a specific format

```
'a:3:{s:8:"postid";s:1:"100";s:6:"commentid";s:1:"200";s:6:"website";s:24:"http://www.example.com";}';
```

Please note that above string is **not** JSON, serialized object or any other data format.

May requirement is to extract the each value in the double quotes and map with the next item in the double quotes.

My required output is an array map

`[postid:100, commentid:200, website:"http://www.example.com"]`

Is this possible to achieve with regular expression? provided keys postid, commentid and website will be always present in the input string.

Comment: Do you have access to the way that data / string is built? Also, what can we assume about that data? What changes in there, and what doesn't?

Comment: Yes this is possible with RegEx. using Match+Groups, you can build this. (seem to me the structure is pretty static "{typecode}:{subcode}:"Value";". Great for RegEx.

Comment: @MarvinSmit: true, but it'll become harder if there are quotes within the value.

Comment: Shouldn't be since the terminator character for the sequence is ';', outside the string. You'll have to play around with greedy versus non greedy queries

Comment: @Cerbrus just need the values in side double quotes and we can discard all other symbols and chars

Comment: @Mithun: Good job, you managed to not answer anything I asked you.

Comment: @Cerbrus sorry, don't have access to the way the string is build, its is sure that the input will have the above 3 keywords in double quotes and 3 other values will be in double quotes following the keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple one should suit your needs:

```
"([^"]+)"[^"]+"([^"]+)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/waazPinuoMDYaGoL)

As you can see, the first group will contain the key and the second one the value.

Demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/iM8rI7/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
"(.*?)";[a-zA-Z]*:\d*:\"(\S+?)"
```

Try this.This will give all groups.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cT1rH4/1